# Detecting extension files doesn't executed for a period

Tags: grep, find

How can I detect the `.class` files in my workspace which haven't executed for a certain period, and remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you can come to finding when a file was last executed is by its `atime` rather than modification time - executing does not modify the files. However, there is no way to tell if the file was accessed for some other reason. Although, if a file hasn't been accessed within a specific time frame, then it can't have been executed.

To list executable files not accessed for over 24 hours you could do:

```
find workspace_dir -type f -perms /111 -atime +1
```

To delete them (**make sure you are only deleting the ones you want to first**):

```
find workspace_dir -type f -perms /111 -atime +1 -exec rm {} +
```

Note that with SSDs it is common to mount with the `noatime` option to reduce the number of disk writes and increase the lifespan. If the filesystem is mounted with the `noatime` option, this won't work.

#### Update

If these are Java `.class` files, then they won't be directly executable. To search for/remove `.class` files accessed over 24 hours ago:

```
find workspace_dir -type f -name '*.class' -atime +1
```

```
find workspace_dir -type f -name '*.class' -atime +1 -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to determine which of the files got modified in the recent time.

```
ls -halt *.class
```

In the above order, the first file in the output means, it was edited recently.

If you want the output in the reverse order,

```
ls -haltr *.class
```

In the above output, the first file in the output means, it was edited long back.

Once you determine the **determinate period**, you can do a `rm` on those files.

Now assuming your determinate period is 1 day, you can run the below command.

```
find /path/to/files* -atime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Another way to delete the files would be,

```
rm -f `find *.class -type f -atime +1`
```

It is always better to specify the full path of the file.

Just to be sure, before running the command, I would run the below command to find out which all files are not modified in the last 1 day.

```
echo `find *.class -type f -atime +1`
```

Comment: `mtime` will only tell you when the file was modified - executing won't modify the file.

Comment: Also if you use `+` instead of `;` with `-exec` it will avoid running a different `rm` process for each file. No need to use `echo` with find either - find will print to `stdout` on its own.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out :) I will make note of these things :)

Answer (score 1):

When program is executed, it is the **atime** that is modified, not ctime or mtime.

NOTE: use `stat <filename>` if you don't believe me.

In order to check what file has been accessed between 2 defined dates, use **-newer** option in find

Example :

`find  ./ -name "*.class" -newerat "2014-03-01" ! -newerat "2014-04-02`"

Will display any file ending in .class and accessed between 1st of March 2014 and 2nd of April 2014.

Comment: you suggest to use the option "newer" but actually you use "newerat"

Comment: This is correct. Check find manpage